# Aligning text center and then left

Tags: css

Good Day

I want to align text in the center of a div. Now that is easy with text-align: center on parent div.

But If I want to left align the text inside the div to the left of the centered div, how do I do that?

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DvXzB/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutContent" class="row-fluid">
    <div id="aboutHeaderText" class="span12"><span title="">About Us</span></div>
    <div id="aboutHeaderBody" class="span12">
        <p><a title="">asdasd</a> is a free mobile application available for <a href="#"
            title="">iOS</a>, <a href="#" title="">Android</a>and the <a href="#" title="">Blackberry</a> operating
            systems.</p>
        <p>sdefsadfsdfldflkjlj lkjlkjdlfsldfjlkj ljlsdjflj lkj ljklj lk; ;l;l; ;k;k
            l;kgjh jhg gjjh jhgjhgjh jhgjh gjg jgjhgjg</p>
        <div id="cities"><a title="">asdasdasd</a> currently only displays events and
            specials in <strong>asdasd</strong> (our hometown), but the following locations
            will be available before you know it:
            <ul>
                <li><span>asdg</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>asdwn</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>Pasdasdroom</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>Dasdaf</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>Bergrin</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>Sersch</span>

                </li>
                <li><span>Graergwn</span>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p>Visit our <a href="" title="" target="_blank">Facebook page</a> for more
            up to date information, and feel free to <a href="" title="">contact us</a> with
            any queries.</p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#aboutContent {
    color: #222;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#aboutHeaderText span {
    font-family:"Kozuka Gothic Pr6N", sans-serif !important;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#aboutHeaderText img {
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#aboutHeaderBody {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#cities ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#cities ul li {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sand-serif;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #222;
}
```

I want the text in the middle of the page to be justified, but when I justify or left align it, it aligns it to the absolute left again. How do I do this without using fixed paddings or margins? Basically what I want is what they have on this page here(see the 'about us' section): http://www.villagebicycle.co.za/

Note: I am using a fluid layout, so fixed paddings etc won't work

Thank you

Comment: sorry, i am not understanding your goal. could you point out a bit clearer what you want? as far as i can see in the linked "about us" the text is always aligned left to a centered div. screenshots might help;)

Comment: @David It is difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to do..could you please clear out.It would be easier to help.

Comment: @David please post your desired result image that would be easier for your to sort out of your problem....

Comment: "aligned left to a centered div"  -exactly what i want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to center align the container with `margin:0 auto` after setting its width to a specific size like `width:400px`. Then align each element separately using `text-align`.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DvXzB/16/

If you want your container to have 100% width then do not use `text-align:center` to your parent `div`. Instead, use `width:100%` (optional) and again `text-align` each block as desired.

Comment: You just saved me some typing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i guess there is no way around setting a fixed width?

Comment: It depends on the case. If you want your container's `width` at 100% of the browser's width, then you just leave your container "as is", meaning: no fixed width, no margin.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use a **wraper** div to envolve all content. I've done a [JsFiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/DvXzB/15/) I think is what you're looking for :)

```
.wraper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;   
}
```

Afther that you can align a `<p>` to the left, right, justify, etc. as you can see:

```
    p.left{text-align:left;}
    p.justify{text-align:justify;}
```

And the HTML for testing:

```
<div class="wraper">
        <p class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

    <p class="justify">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes. If you don't put any width the wrapper will be 100%.